# Be/keep/stay in touch

Tags: grammaticality, colloquialisms

Are all these forms correct?

1. Let's be in touch
2. Let's keep in touch
3. Let's stay in touch

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

To me all three mean different things.

**Let's be in touch**
I say this to someone I've never before met, but during the course of our conversation an important matter emerges which affects us both. It seems important that we maintain contact.

**Let's keep in touch**
I say this to a colleague with whom I have worked for several years, but our future paths are about to diverge.

**Let's stay in touch** 
I have just attended a conference of people working in the same industry. many of the participants were new faces to me, some were old friends. At the end we all appreciate that we have gained a lot from the meeting, and someone says 'let's stay in touch'

I have exaggerated the differences here and any of the three could easily be interchanged with either of the others. But the beauty of English is that there are always multiple ways of saying almost the same thing. So this gives rise to a potential richness, and possibilities for finely nuanced expression. One can bring joy to one's fellows through sweet words; as long as one never forgets that 'sweet words butter no parsnips'.

Comment: I think the first should be: "Let's get in touch"

Comment: +1 for your *"Let's be in touch"* interpretation, as it sorta matches mine. :) -- To me, if I say or hear that version, I'll assume that we'll be making contact soon. The other two versions could easily be mere fluff, the polite stuff we often say with no serious meaning to it (though one or the other of us could actually want future contact).

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Let's get in touch* sort of suggests one hasn't already been in touch. *Let's stay in touch* would be perfect, though.

Answer (score 2):

All correct, but mean different things:

Let's be in touch:  Call me later to discuss this [after an event has occurred].

Let's keep in touch:  I hope to keep hearing from you in the future [now that we've reconnected with each other].

Let's stay in touch:  May mean the same as keep in touch, but also may mean, Check back with me periodically to discuss this.

Comment: Not sure I hear a difference btw keep and stay

Comment: @mplungjan It's subtle.  Stay in touch has a slightly more immediate connotation.

Comment: I am still not convinced that let's be in touch is correct usage. Not that that will keep people from using it...

Comment: @mplungjan Not particularly common.  But, it is acceptable.